# How to prevent Night Theme changing view colors to default colors in android studio?

Tags: android, android-darkmode

Actually it seems very easy. I just want my view not to change its color when DARK THEME is applied. But it keeps changing.

I have even created colors/night and edited theme/night to keep my colors.

For example, I have one ImageButton with white backgroud color. I want its background color stays unchanged even I apply dark theme. But It is getting black when Dark theme applied.

I have read so many answers. But it didn't work. Even some of them are still unanswered.

Is there any way to do that? Or is it some kind of bug?!

Comment: can you share some examples of your problem?

Answer (score 1):

In `app/src/main/res/values/themes.xml`:

Replace `DayNight`

```xml
<style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
```

With `Light`:

```xml
<style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

Comment: I have tried this already. Didn't help. Thank you anyways.